# Transforming the ternary cubic polynomial in to a quaternion cubic homogeneous polynomial Form

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, quaternions

I have a ternary cubic polynomial of the form  $$ P(X,Y,Z) = \sum_{i=0}^{m1}\sum_{j=0}^{m2}\sum_{k=0}^{m3} c_{i,j,k}X^iY^jZ^k$$
how would one write it in quaternion from
i know the the answer should be
$$ f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = \sum (a_i a_j a_k)x_ix_jx_k \ \ where \ x_1=1 $$
but not how to get from one form to the other or why it is correct

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your notation, but don't you have more degrees of freedom for your coefficients in $P$ than $f$.  Also, why is that called "quaternion form"?

Comment: i am using the same notation i read in this article  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.11121.pdf
which i too not completely understand